# WHERE-IN or FIND_IN_SET

Tags: mysql, where-in

An un-normalised db has a table named batches

The table batches has field student_ids with multiple ids in it.   For example `1311,  1319, 1400`

From: SELECT student_ids FROM batches WHERE 1311 IN(student_ids)

we get student_ids: `1311,  1319, 1400`

And: SELECT student_ids FROM batches WHERE 1319 IN(1311, 1319, 1400)

works fine: `1311,  1319, 1400`

but

SELECT student_ids FROM batches WHERE 1319 IN(student_ids)

or

SELECT @student_ids := student_ids FROM batches b;
SELECT student_ids FROM batches WHERE FIND_IN_SET(1319, @student_ids)

returns `Null`

What am I missing?  I think I have to convert the first result into an array - but how?

I have tried Dash's suggestions (many thanks Dash) but I', still having trouble

I've also tried 
SELECT id
FROM batches
WHERE INSTR(','+1319+',', ','+CAST(student_ids AS CHAR) + ',')

as suggested by Matt Ellen on another post - again only works if the first item matches

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT @student_ids := GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(TRIM(student_ids) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)) 
FROM batches b; 

SELECT student_ids 
FROM batches 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(1311, @student_ids) ;
```

or

```
SELECT student_ids FROM batches WHERE CAST(student_ids AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) IN (1319);
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the instant response. Unfortunately this only works for the first id 1311  - if you try 1319 you get null.

Comment: try new query. it should be like `student_ids IN (1319)` try using trim.

Comment: Not quite there yet : the field student_ids is varchar , has data '1311,1319,1400'  and but the IN function can't see past the first item.

Comment: if thats the case then you may need to `cast` that to `integer` or `TRIM` it.